# Force Redirection from http to https nginx to a specific port

Tags: nginx, ssl, port-forwarding, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've a service running in 9000 port and setup ssl using letsencrypt. I would like to forward all request from http to https.

```
http://demo.mydomain.com -> https://demo.mydomain.com 
http://www.demo.mydomain.com -> https://demo.mydomain.com 
www.demo.mydomain.com -> https://demo.mydomain.com
```

Here's my configuration

**vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;

        server_name demo.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}



server {
    if ($host = demo.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;

     server_name demo.mydomain.com;
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     #return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

> # nginx -t
>
> # systemctl reload nginx.service
>
> # curl -I https://demo.mydomain.com -> It works
>
> # curl -I http://demo.mydomain.com -> It times out

I've tried many similar solutions but nothing worked for me. Thanks for any clue.

Comment: Have you read your logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my stupid mistake. Port 80 wasn't open in aws instance. However here's my working configuration for force redirect from http to https for a service running in a different port.

```
server {
        server_name demo.mydomain.com www.demo.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = demo.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;

     server_name demo.mydomain.com;
     #return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Also make sure to open ports 80 and 443. Cheers!